# Unable to parse .csv, .xls, .xlsx file in meteor

Tags: mongodb, csv, meteor, papaparse

I am trying to extract data from .xls, .xlsx But I am getting non-human-readable data in format as shown in image:

[image]

I have tried as many codes as I can but every code endup at same output. I want data as array of objects for each line in excel. Unfortunately I am unable to get it. Below are the codes that I have tried.

***Code1:***
Plugin : [harrison:papa-parse](https://atmospherejs.com/harrison/papa-parse)

```
$('#fileInputId').change(function(e) {

 Papa.parse( e.target.files[0], {
                header: true,
                complete( results, file ) {
                    console.log(results.data);
                  Meteor.call( 'meteorMethodsCall', results.data, ( error, response ) => {
                    if ( error ) {

                    console.log("Upload error");
                    } else {

                    console.log("Upload success");

                    }
                  });
                }
              });
});
```

***Code 2:*** By readFile and adding [d3js:d3](https://atmospherejs.com/d3js/d3)

```
 var readFile = function(f, onLoadCallback) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e){
                    var contents=e.target.result;

                    console.log(contents);                
                    onLoadCallback(contents);
                }; 
                reader.onerror = function(event) {
d3.csv.parse(csv, function( d, i) {
          console.log(i);
          console.log(d);
});
                    console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
                };
                reader.readAsText(f);
            };
```

My excel file looks like:

[image]

Comment: You can't parse an Excel file using CSV methods, as the file format is completely different.

Comment: @NicoHaase Any suggestion how can I do it?

Comment: Don't use XLS files, but CSV files

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=js+xlsx